# Inner product of vector sub space and its orthogonal complement in Hilbert space

Tags: abstract-algebra, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

So im attempting a problem but there is 1 thing I don't understand.

In a Hilbert space of an infinite series $\vec{a}_{i=0}^{\infty}$ we have a sub vector space V for which the following holds: ${a}_{2k+1} = {a}_{2k}$.

Then, in the solutions, the author constructs a basis for the hilbert space $\vec{e}_{i=0}^{\infty}$ which is fine, but then for the inner product, which is defined as $ \langle a | b \rangle $, they write they write the element $a$ as $$\langle {\vec{e}_{2k+1} + \vec{e}_{2k}|b \rangle}= {b}_{2k+1} + {b}_{2k} = 0$$

It equals $0$ because we are constructing the orthogonal complement to V. $\vec{b}$ is thought of as a vector belonging to the orthogonal complement.

***What I don't understand is how we go from the 'condition' of $\vec{e}_{2k+1} = \vec{e}_{2k}$ to, instead of having them equal one another, we write them as a sum.***

My first thought is that it is written as such due to bilinearity? I.e.,

$$\langle {\vec{e}_{2k+1} + \vec{e}_{2k}|b \rangle}= \langle{\vec{e}_{2k+1} | b \rangle} + \langle{\vec{e}_{2k} | b \rangle} = {b}_{2k+1} + {b}_{2k} = 0 $$

If so, then I understand the motivation. ***But how come it is $\vec{e}_{2k+1} + \vec{e}_{2k}$ and not $\vec{e}_{2k+1} - \vec{e}_{2k} = 0$. And why does it specifically yield ${b}_{2k+1} + {b}_{2k}$ ?***

$\vec{e}_{i}$ is an orthonormal basis defined as $\vec{e}_{i}= (\delta_{i,j})_{j}$

Comment: $v = e_{2k+1} + e_{2k}$ is a vector in the space $V$, because its coefficients are $v_{2k} = v_{2k+1} = 1$ and $v_{2i} = v_{2i+1} = 0$ for all $i \ne k$.  So indeed $v_{2i} = v_{2i+1}$ for all $i$.  As such, if $b$ is in the orthogonal complement of $V$ then we must have $\langle v \mid b \rangle = 0$.

Comment: Be careful not to mix up the basis vectors $e_i$ with the coefficients $a_i$.  Our condition defining $V$ is on the coefficients: $a_{2k} = a_{2k+1}$.  Writing $e_{2k} = e_{2k+1}$ doesn't make any sense, they are not the same vector.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks a lot. I didn't spot the fact that it's a vector in V (looks obvious to me now in hindsight). Thanks again!